# Testing with PhpUnit a blade view that contains @include or @extend directives in a Laravel 5 Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, phpunit, laravel-blade

I'm developing a **Laravel package** and I'm trying to figure out how to test with PhpUnit, a **Blade view**  that contains **@include** or **@extend** directives.

This is the structure of the package resource folder:

```
resources
-- views
---- create.blade.php
---- edit.blade.php
---- layout.blade.php
```

The **create** and **edit** views start extending the **layout** one.

```
@extends('vendor.laravel-responsive-gallery.layout')
```

When I install the package in an application and publish the views this works fine, but when I'm in the **test environment** and I run PhpUnit i get the error.

> The response is not a view.

This because PhpUnit cannot resolve the address of the view.

I have tried also with this approach to avoid testing that line of code.

```
@if (env('APP_ENV')!='testing')
    @extends('vendor.laravel-responsive-gallery.layout')
@endif
```

But I PhpUnit throw again the same error.

Since is not possible to assign a relative path to an @extends or @include directive, do you know how can I test my view without commenting this `@extends` line?

I've checked already on Stack overflow and on the Internet but I didn't find any mention to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved registering the view in the ServiceProvider of my package.
Telling that this package provide some views in the /resources/views directory and this views can be accessed using the vendor name of the package `php-responsive-quote`.

```
public function boot(){
     ...
     $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'php-responsive-quote');
     ...
}
```

And then in the view, calling the `@extends` and the `@include` directive in this way.

```
@extends('laravel-responsive-gallery::layout')

@include('laravel-responsive-gallery::partials.input', [
                          'title' => 'Image file name',
                          'name' => 'file_name',
                          'placeholder' => '', 
])
```